# How to pass initializing file for vocabulary table in Tensorflow serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have created a deep learning model that uses a text file to initialize vocabulary table in Tensorflow like below -

```
class MyModel(object):

def __init__(self):
    table_init = tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer('/home/abhilash/resmap.txt', tf.int64, 0, tf.int64, 1, delimiter=" ")
    table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(table_init, num_oov_buckets)
```

`resmap.txt` file has entries like this -

```
2345 1
3456 2
1234 3
```

I convert this TF model into a Tensorflow serving using below code -

```py
from model import MyModel

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('f', '', 'kernel')
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('model_version', 1, 'version number of the model.')
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('save_dir', '/home/abhilash', 'Saving directory.')
    FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

    export_path = os.path.join(tf.compat.as_bytes(FLAGS.save_dir), tf.compat.as_bytes(str(FLAGS.model_version)))
    print('Exporting trained model to', export_path)

    # Creating Model object and initializing all the global variables in TF Graph.
    model = MyModel()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())

    tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, os.path.join('/home/abhilash', 'model1'))
    print("Model restored.")

    # SavedModel Builder Object
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

    # Converting Tensor to TensorInfo Objects so that they can be used in SignatureDefs
    tensor_info_input1 = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.input1)
    tensor_info_input2 = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.input2)
    tensor_info_prob = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.logits_all)

    # SignatureDef
    prediction_signature = (
          tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
              inputs={'input1':tensor_info_input1,
                      'input2':tensor_info_input2},
              outputs={'probs': tensor_info_prob},
              method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
                sess=sess,
                tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                signature_def_map={'predict_prob': prediction_signature},
                main_op=tf.tables_initializer(), 
                strip_default_attrs=False,
                )

    # Export the model
    builder.save()
    print('Done exporting TF Model to SavedModel format!')
```

`model = MyModel()` instantiates TF Graph structure.
Using above code model is converted successfully into `SavedModel` format. And after serving gives correct results.

But when I serve this servable in some different machine, it gives me an error like this -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhilashawasthi/anaconda3/envs/mlflow-95a14f155def99fdbaccbe70ebfbcf3065700c56/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/abhilashawasthi/anaconda3/envs/mlflow-95a14f155def99fdbaccbe70ebfbcf3065700c56/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/abhilashawasthi/anaconda3/envs/mlflow-95a14f155def99fdbaccbe70ebfbcf3065700c56/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/abhilash/resmap.txt; No such file or directory
     [[{{node text_file_init/InitializeTableFromTextFileV2}}]]
```

That is it tries to find that text file at the same location.
So how can I pass this text file so that it gets bundled up with the `SavedModel`?

I saw in the TF Serving documentation that we can pass assets to the serving. But don't how to do that. There are no clear examples available.
Can anyone let me know how to pass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Inference to work from any PC, the Text File which comprises Vocabulary Table should be placed in the **Assets** folder, which is present inside the **Version Numbered Folder** inside the **Folder corresponding to Saved Model**.

So, instead of Saving the Text File **`resmap.txt`** in **`/home/abhilash/resmap.txt`** you should save it in **`/home/abhilash/Saved_Model/1/assets/resmap.txt`**.

Now, when you try performing inference in other machine, you will be copying the Saved Model present in the folder, **Saved_Model**, so the Inference works, as the Vocab file is present inside the Saved Model.

Please find the screenshot below for more clarity

[image]